# How can i message on Instagram live using instabot [python]?

Tags: python-3.x, bots

Here is the code I am doing and unable to find a way to put a message in a live broadcast.

```
from instabot import Bot

bot  = Bot ()

bot.login(username = "XXXXXXX" , password = "XXXXXXXX")
```

Here is an example of a live broadcast :
[example of the live broad cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr4AC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `bot.send_message()` function; e.g.,

```
bot = Bot()

bot.login(username=botusername, password=botpassowrd)

id = bot.get_user_id_from_username('Username')
text = 'This is a testing message by a bot made by Mr.troll_54'

bot.send_message(text, id)
```

If you want to sent messages to more than one account, use:

```
Username_list = ['name1','name2',....]

Id_list = []

for name in Username_list:
    id = bot.get_user_id_from_username('Username')
    Id_list.append(id)
bot.send_messages(text, Id_list)
```